# Fermat Prime Counts

Tags: java

I require help finishing up my java program for this specific exercise, notice that they only ask to find prime numbers in a user imputed interval where the some of both squares are equal to the prime number:

For some reason the input is printing out 0 for the counter.

> In a letter dated December 25, 1640; the great mathematician Pierre de Fermat wrote to Marin Mersenne that he just proved that an odd prime p is expressible as p = a2 + b2 if and only if p is expressible as p = 4c+1. As usual, Fermat did not include the proof, and as far as we know, never wrote it down. It was not until 100 years later that no one other than Euler proved this theorem. To illustrate, each of the following primes can be expressed as the sum of two squares: 5 = 22 + 12 13 = 32 + 22 17 = 42 + 12 41 = 52 + 42 whereas, the primes 11, 19, 23, and 31 cannot be expressed as a sum of two squares. Write a Java program, FermatPrimesCount, to count the number of primes that can be expressed as sum of squares within a given interval. (Arrays may not be used).

```
import java.util.*;
public class FermatPrimesCount
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        int counter=0;
        Scanner Range1= new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner Range2= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input 2 positive integers to set a range 
        for the program to check in: ");
        int min= Range1.nextInt();
        int max= Range2.nextInt();

        Method(min, max, counter);

        System.out.print(counter);
    }
    public static int Method(int min, int max, int counter)
    {

        {
        if (i%2!=0)
            {
            for (int a=1; a<=9; a++)
                {
                for(int b=1; b<=9; b++)
                    {
                    int total=(a*a)+(b*b);
                    System.out.println(total);
                    if (total==i)
                    counter = counter+1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the input is printing out 0 for the counter...

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, but paste your code instead

Comment: would you like me to add it in the comments?

Comment: Apologies for not following the rules...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that counter isn't global in your code, so you have 2 counters. One belongs to the main-method the other to your Method-method. To change this you can basically do `counter = Method(min, max, counter);` because then the returned value from Method is also written to counter.

But hey. Just a little hint. If I look at your code, I see you did not understand Methods and Variables really good. Go to youtube.com and watch some tuts on Java to get better before you do something with Scanners and this stuff because this is really advanved. That's probably also the reason why nobody did help you.